# Azure API-M APIs and Operations with different base URL

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-bicep, apim

In Azure API- Management, If we have a single API set and 2 API operations does the same thing but the newer version now point to a whole new endpoint.

For example below is the BICEP code:

// The APIs sets

```
resource regApi 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2022-08-01' = {
  name: 'register-api-transaction'
  parent: apimService
  properties: {
    displayName: 'Register APIs'
    apiRevision: '1'
    subscriptionRequired: true
    serviceUrl: registerServiceUrl
    path: 'internal/register/search'
    protocols: [
      'http'
      'https'
    ]
    authenticationSettings: {}
    subscriptionKeyParameterNames: {
      header: 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'
      query: 'subscription-key'
    }
    isCurrent: true
  }
}
```

The operations:

```
resource regGetApi 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/operations@2021-08-01' = {
  name: 'name-register-get'
  parent: regApi 
  properties: {
    urlTemplate: '/nameRegister'
    method: 'GET'
    displayName: 'Name register'
    responses: []
  }
}

resource searchGetApi 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/operations@2021-08-01' = {
  name: 'name-search-get'
  parent: regApi 
  properties: {
    urlTemplate: '/nameSearch'
    method: 'GET'
    displayName: 'Name search'
    responses: []
  }
}
```

Question:

What if i want to point one if the operation to a different serviceUrl ? both are pointing to the same parent.

- I do not want to create a new API set
- Can I use versioning in this situation? where the new version will have an altogether new base URL ?

Comment: Yes you can use versioning here as versioning is used to make any changes to the API. @William Fernandes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use [versioning](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/api-management/api-management-versions.md) in this case as versioning is used to make `API` changes.

You can publish multiple **API** versions simultaneously and use a path, query string, or header to distinguish between versions.

To redirect it to different service URL, you can also use the [`set-backend-service`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/api-management/set-backend-service-policy.md#set-backend-service) policy as detailed in the given MS Doc.

Once changes are made, you can also add [Versioning scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/apiversionsets?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#apiversionsetcontractproperties) which is an identifier represents a new version for the existing API.

*I tried below code in my environment which meets your requirement, and the deployment was successful as below.*

```bash
param apiexists string = 'xxxx'
resource apiservice 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2023-03-01-preview' existing = {
  name: apiexists
}
resource regApi 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2022-08-01' = {
  name: 'register-api-transaction'
  parent: apiservice
  properties: {
    displayName: 'Register APIs'
    apiRevision: '2' 
    subscriptionRequired: true
    serviceUrl: '' // Modify this for the new version
    path: 'internal/register/search'
    protocols: [
      'http'
      'https'
    ]
    authenticationSettings: {}
    subscriptionKeyParameterNames: {
      header: 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'
      query: 'subscription-key'
    }
    isCurrent: true
  }
}
//Operations
resource regGetApiV2 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/operations@2021-08-01' = {
  name: 'name-register-get'
  parent: regApi 
  properties: {
    urlTemplate: '/nameRegister'
    method: 'GET'
    displayName: 'xxx'
    responses: []
  }
}

resource searchGetApiV2 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/operations@2021-08-01' = {
  name: 'name-search-get'
  parent: regApi 
  properties: {
    urlTemplate: '/nameSearch'
    method: 'GET'
    displayName: 'xxx'
    responses: []
  }
}
```

In the above code, I have created a new version of the API by modifying the `apiRevision: '2'` and the `serviceUrl` to `newServiceUrl`.

If you want to use the path-based versioning scheme, add the version number (Eg: `"/v2"`)to the path of the API to indicate as version.

*Output:*

[image]

[image]